# JNI attached to program successfully but cant get fields?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, low-level

stackoverflow!

I managed to inject my dll into the game minecraft(made in java) and i did attach to the main thread so i can get classes and field.

Total code:

```html
#include <Windows.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MCClass.h"
/*
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
_In_ HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
_In_ DWORD     fdwReason,
_In_ LPVOID    lpvReserved
);
*/

typedef jint (*hJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs )( JavaVM** vmBuf , jsize bufLen , jsize* nVMs );

hJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs oJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs;

HMODULE jvmHandle;
FARPROC func_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs;
JavaVM *jvm;
JNIEnv *jenv;
jclass Minecraft;
jclass FMLH;
jclass FMLHI;
jclass launchWrapper;
MCClass* mc = new MCClass ( );

using namespace std;

void GetAllMinecraft ( )
{
    
    jfieldID f = jenv->GetFieldID ( Minecraft , "serverName" , "Ljava/lang/String;" );
        if ( f != NULL )
        {
        jstring str = (jstring)jenv->GetObjectField ( Minecraft , f );

        mc->serverName = (char*)jenv->GetStringUTFChars( str , 0 );
        cout << mc->serverName << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL , "serverName is null", "ERROR" , MB_OK );
    }
    
    
}
/*
void start ( )
{
    MessageBox ( NULL , "Initialization has completed." , "Works" , MB_OK );

    FMLH =  jenv->FindClass ( "net/minecraftforge/fml/relauncher/FMLLaunchHandler" );

    if ( FMLH != nullptr )
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLLaunchHandler found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
        jfieldID f = jenv->GetStaticFieldID ( (jclass) FMLH , "INSTANCE" , "Lnet/minecraftforge/fml/relauncher/FMLLaunchHandler;" );
        MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLH passed" , "OK" , MB_OK );
        if ( f == nullptr )
        {
            MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLLaunchHandler fieldID couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLLaunchHandler fieldID found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
            FMLHI = jenv->GetStaticObjectField ( (jclass) FMLH , f );
            MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLHI passed" , "OK" , MB_OK );
            if ( FMLHI == nullptr )
            {
                MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLLaunchHandler instance couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLHI is not nullptr" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                jfieldID f1 = jenv->GetFieldID ( ( jclass ) FMLHI , "classLoader" , "Lnet/minecraft/launchwrapper/LaunchClassLoader;" ); //HERE
                MessageBox ( NULL , "f1 passed" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                if ( f1 == nullptr )
                {
                    MessageBox ( NULL , "classLoader fieldID couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox ( NULL , "classLoader fieldID found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                    launchWrapper = jenv->GetObjectField ( ( jclass ) FMLHI , f1 );
                    MessageBox ( NULL , "launchWrapper passed" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                    if ( launchWrapper == nullptr )
                    {
                        MessageBox ( NULL , "classLoader class couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox ( NULL , "classLoader class found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                        jmethodID mmid = jenv->GetMethodID ( ( jclass ) launchWrapper , "findClass" , "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;" );
                        MessageBox ( NULL , "findClass passed" , "OK" , MB_OK );

                        if ( mmid != NULL )
                        {
                            Minecraft = ( jclass ) jenv->CallNonvirtualObjectMethod ( launchWrapper , ( jclass ) launchWrapper , mmid , "net.minecraft.client.Minecraft" );
                            MessageBox ( NULL , "Minecraft class found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                            //   GetAllMinecraft ( );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox ( NULL , "findClass method ID couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL , "FMLLaunchHandler couldn't be found successfully" , "OK" , MB_OK );
    }


}
*/

const char* GetObjName ( jobject cls )
{


    
    jclass clsClazz = jenv->GetObjectClass ( cls );

    
    jmethodID methodId = jenv->GetMethodID ( clsClazz , "getName" , "()Ljava/lang/String;" );
    jstring className = ( jstring ) jenv->CallObjectMethod ( cls , methodId );

    return jenv->GetStringUTFChars ( className , NULL );

   
    jenv->DeleteLocalRef ( clsClazz );
}
void start ( )
{
    jclass preMC = jenv->FindClass ( "net/minecraftforge/fml/relauncher/FMLLaunchHandler" );

    if ( preMC != NULL )
    {

  /*Section intercept custom findClassStart*/
  jfieldID iID = jenv->GetStaticFieldID ( preMC , "INSTANCE" , "Lnet/minecraftforge/fml/relauncher/FMLLaunchHandler;" );
  cout << "IID: " << iID << endl;
  jobject instance = jenv->GetStaticObjectField ( preMC , iID );
  cout << "INSTANCE: " << instance << endl;
  jfieldID lID = jenv->GetFieldID ( preMC , "classLoader" , "Lnet/minecraft/launchwrapper/LaunchClassLoader;" );
  cout << "LID: " << lID << endl;
  jobject classLoader = jenv->GetObjectField ( instance , lID );
  cout << "classLoader: " << classLoader << endl;
  jmethodID fid = jenv->GetMethodID ( jenv->GetObjectClass(classLoader) , "findClass" , "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;" );
  cout << "FID: " << fid << endl;
  jobject a = jenv->CallNonvirtualObjectMethod ( classLoader , jenv->GetObjectClass(classLoader), fid , "net/minecraft/client/Minecraft" );
  preMC = ( jclass ) a;
  cout << "preMC: " << preMC << endl;
  /*Section intercept custom findClassEND*/

  /*Section getDisplayWidthStart*/
        jfieldID mid = jenv->GetStaticFieldID ( jenv->GetObjectClass(preMC) , "theMinecraft" , "Lnet/minecraft/client/Minecraft;" );
        cout << "MID: " << mid << endl;
        jobject MC = jenv->GetStaticObjectField ( jenv->GetObjectClass(preMC) , mid );
  cout << "MC: " << MC << endl;
  jfieldID mid2 = jenv->GetFieldID ( jenv->GetObjectClass(MC) , "displayWidth" , "I" );
  cout << "MID2: " << mid2 << endl;
  int displayWidth = jenv->GetIntField ( MC , mid2 );
  cout << "DisplayWidth: " << displayWidth << endl;
  /*Section getDisplayWidthEND*/
    }
    

}
void init ( )
{
    jvmHandle = GetModuleHandleA ( "jvm.dll" );
    func_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs = GetProcAddress ( jvmHandle , "JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs" );
    oJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs = ( hJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs ) func_JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs;
    jint returnOF = oJNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs ( &jvm , 1 , NULL );
    
    jint returnOf1 = jvm->AttachCurrentThread ( ( void ** ) &jenv , NULL );

    if ( jenv != nullptr )
    {
        start ( );
    }


    if ( jenv->ExceptionCheck ( ) )
    {
        jenv->ExceptionDescribe ( );
    }

    jvm->DetachCurrentThread ( );


}




BOOL WINAPI DllMain ( HINSTANCE hinstDLL , DWORD fdwReason , LPVOID lpvReserved )
{
    switch ( fdwReason )
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            init ( );
       //case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
       //case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
       //case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    }
}
```

NOTE: this game uses a custom class launcher, + i use the forge api on it.

I looked at the cout debugs and looks like the cout's stop at :

```
cout << "FID: " << fid << endl;
```

After that no more cout's get called. then the game stops responding.
Thank you for reading and hopefully i was descriptive enough.

EDIT: The whole code stops the game minecraft from responding after some time or instantly idk its random.

I use standard injection with extreme injector for now.

This is some information i got from debugging:

```html
IID: 0000000024D1FE80
INSTANCE: 00000000191813F8
LID: 0000000000000032
classLoader: 0000000019181400
FID: 0000000016176C90
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002d7688e, pid=6048, tid=0x0000000000001648
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_92-b14) (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.92-b14 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# J 3576 C2 net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (695 bytes) @ 0x0000000002d7688e [0x0000000002d76820+0x6e]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Balen\Desktop\ForgeMod\eclipse\hs_err_pid6048.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
:runClient FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8 mins 50.128 secs
```

Edit: This is to better explain everything:

I inject this dll into the game after everything in the game has initialized.

The games uses a custom class loader(LaunchClassLoader) i try to retrieve a instance of that, to do so i get the FMLLaunchHandler there i get a instanceof FMLLaunchHandler then from that instance i get classLoader and from that instance i use the classLoaders findClass to get the class.

Someone told me that i need to get a initialized version of a class to use non static methods or get non static fields.

I use a injector called extreme injector for now and use standard injection which is loadlibrary.

I also do not create my own vm, i attach to the running minecraft vm and get the env from that thru a dll and init function handles the attaching.

Thanks for reading, have nice day.

Comment: *it returns MC: 0000000000000000 and ... i ignored that*  Bad idea.  You *can't* ignore that.  It's likely that the static field hasn't been initialized yet.  *The whole code stops the game minecraft from responding after some time or instantly idk its random.*  That's not surprising as you tried to get the class of a NULL object.  It's undefined behavior.

Comment: I did change the code to a better one but still errors, its like i come out of the dark and then lose my way again and go back to the dark.

Comment: Your example isn't really complete.  How are you loading your DLL?  When is your `start()` function getting called?  Is there any way you can tell if the static field you're trying to access has been initialized?  Your start method may be getting called before the Minecraft code initialization code runs.

Comment: Thanks for being a really nice support, <3. I updated the question with everything any debugger needs to help me with this use. Have a nice day.

Comment: It seems that the crashing call is `CallNonvirtualObjectMethod`. Why don't you use `CallObjectMethod`? Is there also a crash with that one?

Comment: CallNonvirtualObjectMethod is crashing indeed tho i tried callobjectmethod and its same.